# Using a php array in materialize autocomplete

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, materialize

I am trying to initialize the [materialize autocomplete](https://materializecss.com/autocomplete.html) using a simple PHP array ($keysArray). I am converting the PHP array into Javascript using json_encode but for some reason the below doesn't work. The autocomplete dropdown simply doesn't appear - it only works when I type up the keys directly like in the example in the MaterializeCSS link under 'Initialisation'.

```
var tempArray = <?php echo json_encode($keysArray); ?>;
const ac = document.querySelector('.autocomplete');
  M.Autocomplete.init(ac, {
    source: tempArray;
  });
```

Below is a copy of the array structure:

```
  $keysArray = array (
    "Test1",
    "Test2",
    "Test3"
  );
```

Answer (score 1):

According to Initialisation information, you should be using data not source.

```
var tempArray = <?php echo json_encode($keysArray); ?>;
    const ac = document.querySelector('.autocomplete');
    M.Autocomplete.init(ac, {
      data: tempArray;
    });
```

Also they are using an object, not an array:

```
$keysArray = {
    "Test1" : null,
    "Test2" : null,
    "Test3" : null
  };
```

Comment: I should have mentioned that I already tried this but unfortunately no luck. Thanks anyway.

Comment: can you post a copy of your array?

Comment: Absolutely. I added the array in my post.

Comment: I updated my answer, they are using an object not an array.

Answer (score 0):

I wrote a little snippet to convert an array into an object of the format {"test1":null,"test2":null}.

```
myObjectForAutocomplete =  myArray.reduce((obj, item) => {
  obj[item['oneOfYourPropertiesFromArrayItem']] = null
  return obj
}, {});
```